# Шаблон для номера телефона

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

У меня такой вопрос кто-нибудь знает `RegExp` шаблон для номера телефона (СНГ)? Желательно чтобы умел разбирать:

1. `(` и `)`
2. `-`
3. + (в начале номера)
4. (это пробел)
5. Обычные городские номера

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: [Хабропост](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110731/):

>`^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$`

Comment: С поправкой, что в СНГ не только +7 префикс.

Comment: Ну и еще надо добавить шестизначные городские. В этой регулярке только семизнаки

Comment: В маленьких городах еще пятизначные номера есть, я это гарантирую. Но я бы трижды подумал перед тем как принимать номер телефона в сокращенном формате, и делал бы это только, если однозначно известно где абонент живет (т.е. префикс города).

Comment: @ReinRaus к сожалению, данное регулярное выражение не будет соответствовать логике, потому, что, длина телефона не соответствует. Разный код, регион, что-либо - могут ввести в заблуждения. Я думаю, что на этот счет, нужно давать пользователям, писать достоверную информацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решил сделать так. Сначало отсеить все нецифровые значения номера, исключения сделать только для всяких скобо, дефисов, пробелов и т.д.

```
regV = /^([+]?[0-9\s-\(\)]{3,25})*$/i;
```

Потом привести их все к нормальному виду. Например вот так:

```
function phone(name) {
    "use strict";
    var r = /([0-9])+/g, arr = name.match(r), res, str = arr.join('');
    if (name.substr(0, 1) === '+') {
            res = "+" + str;
    } else if (str.substr(0, 1) === '8') {
            res = "+7" + str.substr(1);
    } else {
            res = str;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Дак в данном случае любой набор цифр будет верным и даже при `/^([+]?[0-9\s-\(\)]{3,25})*$/i`  - сомнительное регулярное выражение., я думаю для таких целей, подойдет код города и номер телефона.

Answer (score 2):

```
^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$
```

Ориентировано на российские мобильные + городские с кодом из 3 цифр (например, Москва). Пропускает:

```
+79261234567
89261234567
79261234567
+7 926 123 45 67
8(926)123-45-67
123-45-67
9261234567
79261234567
(495)1234567
(495) 123 45 67
89261234567
8-926-123-45-67
8 927 1234 234
8 927 12 12 888
8 927 12 555 12
8 927 123 8 123
```

Comment: на телефоне не работает, 2 цифры в скобках, потом пусто

Answer (score 0):

([\+]?[7|8][\s-(]?[9][0-9]{2}[\s-)]?)?([\d]{3})[\s-]?([\d]{2})[\s-]?([\d]{2})

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -2):

Пользуюсь давно вот этой регуляркой и очень рад:

```
(\s*)?(\+)?([- _():=+]?\d[- _():=+]?){10,14}(\s*)?
```

Comment: Данное регулярное выражение, также будет выбирать любой диапазон цифр до 14 к сожалению... Для более верного решения, нужно учитывать код города и номер телефона включительно.